# Athena table with a list of all EC2 stopped machines and their stop date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-quicksight, amazon-ebs

I'm trying to create a Quicksight dashboard with a list of all Stopped ec2 instances and their cost. Not sure how can I get a list of all Stopped instances with their stop date and attached EBS volume and its size.
Any advice?

Comment: Take a look at [AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/WhatIsConfig.html). It keeps a history of resources. You can't query it directly in QuickSight, but you can probably extract the data you need and put it into a database for querying.

Comment: Maybe Athena queries might help